# How to use a label to dispaly the combination of string and URL with underline

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, label

I am using a bel which will have to display the string which is a combination of string and url.

For example:
 Refer to this: `https://www.google.com/` or `https://www.google.com/` watch this.

I need to display entire string in the same label but the URL should be underlined.

How to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `FormattedText`

```
<Label>
  <Label.FormattedText>
    <FormattedString>
      <Span Text="First " />
      <Span TextDecorations="Underline" Text="http://www.google.com" />
      <Span Text=" Third" />
    </FormattedString>
  </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>
```